# MySQL Filter on many-to-many

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a many-to-many with the following tables:

1) receipts

```
-id
-name
```

2) ingredients

```
-id
-name
```

3) receipts-ingredients

```
-recept_id
-ingredient_id
```

Now i want to find the receipts that have a list of ingredients. For example all receipts that have the ingredients 'tomato' AND 'pesto'. (And not the receipts that have only 'tomato' or 'pesto'. How will the query look like?

Comment: Either self join, or GROUP BY. (School work?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT r.id, r.name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(i.name)) as items
 FROM receipts r
 LEFT JOIN receipts-ingredients ri ON(ri.receipt_id = r.id)
 LEFT JOIN ingredients i ON(ri.ingredient_id = i.id)
 GROUP BY r.id
 HAVING FIND_IN_SET('tomato',items) AND FIND_IN_SET('pesto',items)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It gives the resultset that i needed. Its more complex then i expected.

Answer (score 1):

Found another working answer on a dutch board:

```
SELECT
    r.id,
    r.name
FROM
    receipts r
JOIN
    receipts_ingredients ri
    ON r.id = ri.receipt_id
JOIN
    ingredients i
    ON ri.ingredient_id = i.id
WHERE i.name IN ('tomato', 'pesto')
GROUP BY r.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM ingredients AS i 
LEFT JOIN `receipts-ingredients` AS ri ON i.id=ri.ingredient_id 
LEFT JOIN receipts AS r ON ri.recept_id=r.id 
WHERE i.name='tomato') AS Tomato, JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM ingredients AS i 
LEFT JOIN `receipts-ingredients` AS ri ON i.id=ri.ingredient_id 
LEFT JOIN receipts AS r ON ri.recept_id=r.id 
WHERE i.name='pesto') AS Pesto ON Tomato.recept_id=Pesto.recept_id
```

Comment: That means a subquery?

Comment: @Frankbeen see query

Comment: Thank you but your query gave results on only 'tomato' or only 'pesto'.

Comment: Oh, than you have to join two subqueries. The editet query should work @Frankbeen

Answer (score 0):

This is a hardcoded approach (there are better answers) but you can also use this for the particular data (FYI: i added the character 'i' at column 'recept_id' of 'receipts-ingredients' table).

EDIT

Also you may need to put backticks around the receipts-ingredients table name. Maybe it would be a good idea to rename it to receipts_ingredients.

```
SELECT aa.id, aa.name AS receipts_name
FROM receipts AS aa
INNER JOIN `receipts-ingredients` AS bb
ON aa.id = bb.receipt_id
INNER JOIN ingredients AS cc
ON cc.id = bb.ingredient_id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT aa.id
    FROM receipts AS aa
    INNER JOIN `receipts-ingredients` AS bb
    ON aa.id = bb.receipt_id
    INNER JOIN ingredients AS cc
    ON cc.id = bb.ingredient_id
    WHERE cc.name = 'pesto' 
) _aa
ON aa.id = _aa.id
WHERE cc.name = 'tomato'
```